# Javascript is only working inline

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a problem where my javascript is not working in a separate file, but it is working inline.

This is the working code with my javascript in line. This is in asp.net 4.0.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="FrontEnd.master.cs"   Inherits="pigninja.FrontEnd" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowItem(itemID) {
        document.getElementById(itemID).style.visiblity = "visible";
    }

    function HideItem(itemID) {
        document.getElementById(itemID).style.visiblity = "hidden";
    }
</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Pigninja Paradox</title>
    <link href="../Styles/Styles.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="pageWrapper">
        <div id="header">
        </div>
        <div id="navigation">
            <div id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="../Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../About.aspx">About Me</a>
                        <div id="submenu">
                            <ul>
                                <li onmouseout="HideItem('submenu');" onmouseover="ShowItem('submenu');"><a href="1983.aspx">
                                    1983</a></li>
                                <li><a href="1988.aspx">1988</a></li>
                                <li><a href="1990s.aspx">1990's</a></li>
                                <li><a href="2000.aspx">2000</a></li>
                                <li><a href="present.aspx">Present</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="../Programming.aspx">Programming</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../Rants.aspx">Rants</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Content" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <p>
                I'd rather be an outlaw then to fall to Babylon law</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is as soon as I change this to

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/navBarScript.js">  </script>
```

My code no longer works and I can't for the life of me figure out why.

Comment: did you look into firebug whats causing the problem. it seems to me that you just have a path issue there.

Comment: Did you check the browser console to see what errors it reports?  It might either tell you that it can't find your external JS file (so it isn't loading) or that you have a script error in it when it executes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why this fixed it, but I ended up changing my script to

```
function ShowItem(itemID){
document.getElementById(itemID).style.display = "block";
}

function HideItem(itemID){
document.getElementById(itemID).style.display = "none";
}
```

After these changes my code performed as expected. I do not know how or why. But this resolved my issue.

Comment: I should also note that I checked the path to the script multiple times and it was always set accordingly. I made no changes to my path, only these changes in the script and like magic, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Make absolutely sure that the src path your of your script is correct, you could always set it as such

```
src="/scripts/navBarScript.js"
```

Starting with a / to reference from the base, There is no reason for it to not work

Also, put the external script tag inside the head or just before the closing body tag